# Short story involving ceramic pottery with a beautiful shine, and an inspector who is killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

An inspector from Earth is stationed on a planet where the inhabitants have a special way of making pottery with a perfect, compelling glaze, as if the vase has a "soul". That indeed turns out to be the case when the inspector learns the secret and is no longer, i.e. the new vase that is donated to the Earth ambassador is a beautiful piece.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is this a question you've asked previously, and you've copy-pasted it to ask it again?

Comment: @F1Krazy I have a section a quick Google and didn’t turn anything up but the links pasted in is a bit strange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Might this be *[The Potters of Firsk](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52209)* by Jack Vance? It was originally published in [the May 1950 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57597) of *Astounding Science Fiction* magazine, and later reprinted in [various collections](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25634319-the-potters-of-firsk).

[image: Cover of the Astounding Science Fiction May 1950 issue, showing a humanoid figure crossing furry arms. The figure has yellow eyes, and is standing in front of a body of water. There is a cliff with a building at the top next to the body of water.]

Judging by this review from Goodreads, it seems to be a near-perfect match to your description:

> "The Potters of Firsk" is a nineteen page short story that was published originally in 1950 in Astounding Science Fiction magazine. It is a very imaginative, creative story that demonstrates how early in his career Vance was able to produce well written, interesting stories.
>
> **The main character, Thomm, is asked about a beautiful bowl on his desk and tells the story of how he obtained it on the planet Firsk from fierce, secretive potters who used human bones in their glazes. These potters usually used the bones of the deceased per an ancient agreement with the local people. But "when the need is great, we do anticipate nature by a year or two...The soul lives forever in the pot it beautifies."** One of Thomm's assignments on Firsk was to make sure that local people were not captured alive and used for their bones when the bone supply was low.

And having listened to [this radio play](https://ia802508.us.archive.org/31/items/OTRR_Dimension_X_Singles/Dimension_X_1950-07-28__17_PottersOfFirsk.mp3) of the story, I can confirm that

> the character who is killed by the potters near the end of the story, and whose bones were use to glaze the bowl on (the protagonist) Thomm's desk, was actually his immediate superior on the planet Firsk, George Covill. He wasn't a very likeable man, repeatedly referring to the people of the native Mi-Tuun race as "gooks", so I don't think we were meant to be all that broken up about his death.

You can read a preview of the story [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Potters_of_Firsk_and_Other_Stories/NFHNJK4tJC0C?hl).

Comment: Amazing, within 2 hours the answer to something that has puzzeld me for ove 10 years.

Comment: You can read the whole story here https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v45n03_1950-05_cape1736#page/n87/mode/1up